# Resetting Display brightness/gamma on external Display doesn't work

Tags: display, brightness

I managed to mess up the output on my external Display. I don't know how, exactly. I am running Pop OS and recently upgraded to 19.10. Shortly after I noticed the problem that the display settings on my my external monitor are messed up. There seems to be a gamma/brightness misadjustment. The screen is not (only) too bright but lacks contrast. 
I had the same problem a while ago when the brightness settings of a game (Urban Terror) messed up the brightness of the screen, even after the game was closed. So maybe it's this problem again. I used to solve it by running the game, changing the brightness to default and exit. Now that doesn't work anymore.
What I tried: 
- Adjusting the brightness and gamma values through xrandr. I tried setting everything to "1", as well as trying different values. I could change the output, but not get rid of the problem entirely, there is still a very visible lack of contrast. It's like there is a layer of fog in front of the screen.

-Since the display used to work ok out of the box I thought I could just remove the display mode through xrandr, hoping I could set everything as it was originally when reconnected.
It didn't work though, here is the output:

```
X@pop-os:~$ xrandr --delmode DP-2-2 1920x1080
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (RRDeleteOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  40
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

In a pretty similar question this bug was referred, but not resolved:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11-xserver-utils/+bug/364091

- I also tried removing the monitors.xml file, didn't work either.

Is there a way to just set everything back to zero? I don't need any of the settings that I used, so if everything would be at the default settings again I would be happy.. I am sorry if I should have posted the question in one of the existing similar threads, or split this question into several more specific ones.

---UPDATE---
As requested, outputs before and after trying to change the brightness.
Note: " Gamma:      0.44:1.0:2.0" is the result of the night/sleep mode. The problem still remains after changing the brightness.

```
xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness: -B5
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x48) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  4250628
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.44:1.0:2.0
    Brightness: 0.68
--
DP-2-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1b6) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x1b4
    Timestamp:  4250628
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.44:1.0:2.0
    Brightness: 0.68
x@pop-os:~$ xrandr --output DP-2-2 --brightness 1
x@pop-os:~$ xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness: -B5
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x48) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  4380216
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.44:1.0:2.0
    Brightness: 0.68
--
DP-2-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1b6) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x1b4
    Timestamp:  4380216
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
```

Comment: There was an issue last week where Ubuntu users were offered to automatically upgrade to Pop OS 19.10 which I would consider a bug but it was attributed to pop PPA being active.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I would suggest that you make this an answer and maybe expand on this.

Comment: I'm moving this to Unix & Linux, since you're using Pop! OS. Have you rebooted the system since this problem occurred? Typically, I've never had the gamma settings be kept after a reboot.

Comment: @RolandiXor Yes the problem remains after rebooting. Tried it several times, with external screen connected and without it and then connecting it later. The gamma values, as returned from xrandr, are at 1:1:1. So it doesn't appear as if changed gamma settings are kept, but the output looks as if gamma or brightness are somehow messed up.

Comment: Update your question with output from `xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness: -B5` before and after trying to change brightness. Include the `xrandr` command usied to change the brightness in between.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sry for the late answer, spent some time with the family and without the computer. Added the requested outputs.